# Galactic Gas Pockets - Rendering Real Galaxy Supercomputer Simulations in Blender

Tags: materials, node-editor, geometry-nodes

Node noob calling node gurus.

This is the second part of a hobby background project ([first part here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291412/remove-every-nth-vertex-with-geometry-nodes-python/291418#291418)) to my dissertation focus, aimed at using blender to render a galaxy generated on my university's supercomputer. This stage of the project is a materials-based node challenge.

[image]

Every vertex shown here represents a bubble of relatively cold gas of the interstellar medium (ISM). I would like to use nodes to give each point a 'bubble' that procedurally merges with its neighbouring bubbles to create one eventual surface.

These bubbles are eventually to appear as transluscent clouds with an irridescent blue sheen (I'll play with the material in a bit, to maximise '*coolness*' (drum noises). I'll then use the same node architecture to render the hot ISM, and then I can move on to generating the stars.

All aid / ideas welcome :)

Comment: Hello. From your description it seems like you may want to try instancing meta balls instead of your vertices. Although the sheer number of them will likely make Blender crash. Try with a low sample and see if it suits your need. Otherwise you can try using a native point cloud instead of a mesh and play with the point radius, although since they're not actual geometry they won't blend with each other. Another solution is to wait for the SDF volume nodes which should ship with then next release (I think) - or try it out now with the beta version

Comment: ...A simplified blend file might be helpful.